# Calling variable from automator in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

I am struggling to call the 'folder' variable within my apple script (shown in the image).
I don't have much experience with apple script so I'm sure I'm not calling it correctly but I can't find a better example online.
Any help would be appreciated.

[AppleScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYe0Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a *variable action*.

The result of the first action is passed to the second as a list of alias specifiers.

`item 1 of input` is the desired item, you just have to coerce it to `POSIX path`

[image]

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense now. I did forget to add the rest of the script in the photo. After I CD that variable I wanted to run a second command right after. Would I just ad && to call a new command EG: do script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of item 1 of input && "mhl seal -t md5 *"

Comment: The single `&` is the AppleScript operator to concatenate strings. The shell `&&` operator must be inside the literal string. `do script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of item 1 of input & " && mhl seal -t md5 *"`